# Javascript Flow Chart or Static Flow Chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say that we have the following image:

I'm thinking of drawing this image with all the possible connections and then position some labels on their correspondent arrow... but this may not be the best approach, because the position of each label would be different depending on screen resolution. What do you think about this approach?

[image]
My question is: anyone knows any JavaScript library, jQuery plugin capable of drawing something like the image above? I mean, capable of doing multiple connections and that could be implemented with AngularJS ?

#### **Here are some new details:**

After I make some tests with JointJS, I think it is what I need, but...
the following [link](http://onwi.net/tests/jointjs/demo/_demo.html) is an example of JointJS with a demo of connections/links between sources and targets that I would have on this project... The thing is: as you can see on this demo has alot of links and it's hard to interpret. Can anyone help me on how to make this look better? There's a better way of representing this? (on this example the link's are static but they would be done on a dynamically way).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out below urls:

JSPlumb provides a means for a developer to visually connect elements on their web page

http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/flowchart/jquery.html

http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/jquery.html

Wirekit looks good for creating custom wired flows:

http://neyric.github.com/wireit/

JointJS is a modern HTML 5 JavaScript library for visualization and interaction with diagrams and graphs.

http://www.jointjs.com/

Comment: I Appreciate your reply. I have tested jsPlumb for this project but it's not the best approach because sometimes I have too many connections and it looks like a mess. However I looked into JointJS and it seems great I'm going to test it.. there's any chance of you know about an AngularJS directive for JointJS?

Comment: Hi, how well did your tests go? What library did you decided to use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice angular library

https://github.com/codecapers/AngularJS-FlowChart

and an example of it in action

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16408368/WebUI_FlowChart/index.html